# The maximum number of stages in explicit and implicit Runge Kutta methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, runge-kutta-methods

I am working on deriving the explicit and implicit Runge Kutta methods. And here is my temporatory work [Runge Kutta methods](https://hongnguyenquanba.wordpress.com/2016/10/02/assignment-runge-kutta-method/).

In general, the Runge Kutta order $p$ method, i.e., $ \displaystyle O\left( {{{h}^{{p+1}}}} \right)$ need some numbers of step $s$. In [wiki introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods), one have bounded $\displaystyle \min s$ for the explicit Runge Kutta order $p$ method. I wonder if there is a above bound for $s$, i.e., $\displaystyle \max s$ for the explicit Runge Kutta order $p$ method and the implicit ones?

Comment: There is no maximum number, you can always add redundancy. Did you mean upper bounds for the minimum number of stages? -- Read up on Butcher trees for a systematic construction of the coefficient equations. The first pitfall occurs in the order 4 equations, the term $f_yf_{yy}[f,f]$ is in the vector case different from $f_{yy}[f_yf,f]$, in your paper you seem to treat them the same.

Comment: In my paper, I derive Runge Kutta methods in the most elementary way. I have not studied Butcher trees yet. Hence, my way takes a vast of complicated computations than Butcher trees. Thanks @LutzL :)